# How can i get viewport cavity data?

Tags: shader-nodes

I am trying to create a cavity map in Blender.
I try many ways which I found in youtube or other websites,but the result is not I want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WX9J_LChpjE

I found this man are trying to rebuild blender view port cavity with shader editor,then i realized how good the view port cavity is.considering blender able to generate this cavity in view port,can we get the view port cavity data?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how you want to use this? It's basically short-range AO.. and you _can_ render from the workbench (viewport-solid) renderer itself.. How you choose to generate / capture the AO would depend on your use-case, I think?